# MODX getPage shows empty results when using MIGX

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I can't figure out why getPage displays empty results while using it with MIGX. I have 5 items to display and 4 items can be displayed on each page. However getPage displays 8 items  in total 4 on page 1 and 4 on page 2, 3 of the items on page 2 is empty.

The code i am using is:

```
[[!getPage?
    &element=`getImageList`
    &tvname=`news` 
    &tpl=`news`
    &limit=`4`
]]
```

Am I missing something? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was fixed in this commit:

https://github.com/Bruno17/MIGX/commit/77f2f62f9532801ae0962bcf16d673b03fbceaae

Look for the changes to this file: core/components/migx/elements/snippets/getimagelist.snippet.php

It hasn't made it into the transport package yet.

In the meantime, you can fix it in your copy.

Hope this helped